# Panda's left merge: resulting table has more rows, prevent duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 dataframes. df1 has 39780 rows and df2 has 8900454 rows

The columns of df1 I want to merge on: 
`['postalcode','housenumber', 'suffix']`
The 'suffix' column contains some NAN's.

df2 columns:

```
['postalcode_right','housenumber_right', 'suffix_right', 'index_right']
```

(the column named 'index_right' is not the index of that dataframe.)

```
df2 = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='left', left_on=['postalcode','housenumber', 'suffix'], right_on = ['postalcode_right','housenumber_right', 'suffix_right'])
```

Because df1.suffix contains NAN's some rows on the right matches multiple rows on the left.

How can I prevent this OR clear the 'index_right' values of the rows that matched multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't look to group by null values. For one, it doesn't make much sense from an analytical perspective.

You can convert your `NA` values to a filler string, e.g. `'NULL'`:

```
left_cols = ['postalcode', 'housenumber', 'suffix']
right_cols = ['postalcode_right', 'housenumber_right', 'suffix_right']]

df1[left_cols] = df1[left_cols].fillna('NULL')
df2[right_cols] = df2[right_cols].fillna('NULL')
```

Then drop duplicates in your `right` dataframe before merging:

```
res = pd.merge(df1, df2.drop_duplicates(subset=right_cols), 
               how='left', left_on=left_cols, right_on=right_cols)
```

This will ensure `res` has the same number of rows as `df1`.